# SQL*Plus screen size causes column heading alignment issue

Tags: oracle, powershell, sqlplus, instantclient

When the SQL*Plus column headings line exceeds the PowerShell screen buffer size (in this case) by 4 or more, the window wraps the column heading line with the incorrect number of spaces.

This causes the column heading to not align with the values.

I get the same result regardless if `set trim on` or `set trim off`.

I get the same result regardless if `set wrap on` or `set wrap off`.

Is this a bug in PowerShell, Oracle InstantClient, or am I using SQL*Plus incorrectly?

Using Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition, Oracle InstantClient 19c 64-bit, Windows PowerShell Desktop 5.1.19041.1320, Microsoft Windows 10.0 build 19042.

PowerShell screen buffer size of 31.  Column heading `B` is aligned with its data.

```sql
SQL> create table wrap (a varchar2(20), b varchar2(10));

Table created.
 
SQL> insert into wrap (a, b) values ('12345678901234567890', 'abcdefghij');
 
1 row created.
 
SQL> commit;
 
Commit complete.
 
SQL> set linesize 31
SQL> select * from wrap;
 
A                    B
-------------------- ----------
12345678901234567890 abcdefghij
```

PowerShell screen buffer size of 17.  There are 16 spaces after column heading `A` and 0 spaces after column heading `B`.  Column heading `B` is aligned with its data.

```sql
SQL> select * fro
m wrap;
 
A               
    B
-----------------
--- ----------
12345678901234567
890 abcdefghij
```

PowerShell screen buffer size of 16.  There are 0 spaces after column heading `A` and 2 spaces after column heading `B`.  Column heading `B` is **not** aligned with its data.

```sql
SQL> select * fr
om wrap;
 
A
             B 
----------------
---- ----------
1234567890123456
7890 abcdefghij
```

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable
 
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1320
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1320
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just an FYI, we have a more modern CLI for Oracle Database called SQLcl that you might find more user friendly. oracle.com/sqlcl

Comment: did you try with 'set tab off'? I don't have windows, so can't test, but on linux, sqlplus does not behave the same way

Comment: Of course it wraps when it exceeds the screen width.  What do you expect?  If the screen width is 80 characters,  what do you expect it to do if you send it more than 80 characters?  Setting linesize in sqlplus simply tells it the maximum number of chracters between liine feeds.  If you say linesize=30, it will put a line feed after 30 characters, even if the window is 80 characters wide.  And buffer size has absolutely nothing to do with it.  I set _column_ sizes, and spool output, opening the spool file in a text editor with adjustable line widths.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith.  I am now watching your "Command Line SQL with SQLcl" AskTOM Ofice hours with Chris Saxon.  Thanks.

Comment: @EdStevens.  I expect it to wrap both the column heading and data consistently.  See the example in the OP with size of 16.  Column heading ``B`` is in position 14 while its data starts in position 6.  The issue does not occur when Window Size is 16 and Screen Buffer Size is greater than 16.  Hence, the distinction made.

Comment: @gsalem.  ``set tab off`` seems to work.  It preserves the spaces after the column heading ``A``, thus causing column heading ``B`` to fall in the correct position when the heading line is wrapped by the Screen Buffer Size setting.  Thanks.